# How do I resolve linker warning "ignoring linker optimzation hint at" in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, webrtc

A google search for "ignoring linker optimzation hint" practically turns up nothing. NOTE: "optimzation" is the exact spelling :)

I'm using a 3rd party WebRTC library (libjingle_peerconnection) from Pristine in one of my apps and I get warnings when I build for my iPhone 6. I'm not sure if this warning will pop up for other devices, however, it does not appear when I build for the simulator.

I have exactly 68 of these bad boys in my build output:

> ld: warning: ignoring linker optimzation hint at _cftmdl_128_neon+0xF0 because ldrInfoC.offset == 0

I'm not sure if I should notify the maintainers or if this is something I can resolve myself.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same warnings

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling the WebRTC library by yourself using build scripts, the warnings are generated because of a missing parameter in `GYP_DEFINES`.

In order to fix the warnings, the WebRTC library needs to be compiled again with the parameter `clang_xcode=1` in the `GYP_DEFINES` setting, like below (only an example):

```
export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES OS=ios target_arch=arm64 clang_xcode=1"
```

More about the issue can be found here, on the Chromium forums:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5182

--

If you're not compiling the WebRTC library yourself, and instead installing the WebRTC library from a 3rd party source, I don't believe there is a fix as the warnings are stemming from the static library.