# Manual import of Twilio into Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm building a framework target to be used across multiple apps I am developing and I'm trying to include the Twilio SDK (TwilioCommon & TwilioConversationsClient) in this common framework target.

To do so, I had to create a [modulemap to define a module from the headers](https://github.com/cklab/twilio-warnings/blob/master/modules/Twilio/module.modulemap). Ok, great. Everything seems to work fine. Except I'm getting an excessive number of warnings when following this model:

```
ld: warning: ignoring linker optimzation hint at _cftmdl_128_neon+0xF0 because ldrInfoC.offset == 0
ld: warning: ignoring linker optimzation hint at _cftmdl_128_neon+0xFC because ldrInfoC.offset == 0
ld: warning: ignoring linker optimzation hint at _cftmdl_128_neon+0x108 because ldrInfoC.offset == 0
....
....
```

I believe I've adhered to the [Manual install for iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#ios-sdk) page fairly well and I've created a [minimal project on github](https://github.com/cklab/twilio-warnings) to replicate this behavior.

Anyone able to spot mistakes? Is this a bug in the way the library was linked?

Versions and things:

```
XCode 7.2.1, Swift 2
TwilioCommon 0.2.0
TwilioConversationsClient 0.22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is remarkably similar to this one:
[How do I resolve linker warning "ignoring linker optimzation hint at" in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820679/how-do-i-resolve-linker-warning-ignoring-linker-optimzation-hint-at-in-xcode)

> If you're compiling the WebRTC library by yourself using build
>   scripts, the warnings are generated because of a missing parameter in
>   GYP_DEFINES.
>
> In order to fix the warnings, the WebRTC library needs to be compiled
>   again with the parameter clang_xcode=1 in the GYP_DEFINES setting,
>   like below (only an example):
>
> export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES OS=ios target_arch=arm64
>   clang_xcode=1" More about the issue can be found here, on the Chromium
>   forums: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5182
>
> --
>
> If you're not compiling the WebRTC library yourself, and instead
>   installing the WebRTC library from a 3rd party source, I don't believe
>   there is a fix as the warnings are stemming from the static library.